# Updating Kendo Strip Tab fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am not sure why there is not much information on this functionality but I am having problems with something I thought would be very easy. Following is what I want to do.

- I have already loaded my tab control which has one of its tabs listing some items
- Now, I am adding an item in the list using a completely different partial View and once it is loaded I want the tab flawlessly updated using AJAX.

I am using following code to TRY to reload the tab:

```
 var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip();
                 var somethingelse =  tabstrip.data('kendoStrip');
                 var item = somethingelse.items()[1];
                tabStrip.reload(item);
```

When I put debugger on this what I figured is that $("#tabstrip") does get identified at the run time **BUT** both **$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip();** and 
**tabstrip.data('kendoStrip');** return unidentified and all the subsequent actions fail. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code like this

```
var tabstrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip();
            var kendoTabStrip = tabstrip.data().kendoTabStrip;
            var item = kendoTabStrip.items()[1];
            kendoTabStrip.reload(item);
            $("#Kendowindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
```

[reload documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#methods-reload)